# What is the definition of an extremum of a function?

Tags: calculus, optimization, applications

In calculus extremum is a common topic, but I don't understand what it is. What is the use of this extremum, especially in practical life?

Comment: In practical life? When you'll by a car, did you ask about the maximum for the price or discount? Or the maximum to wait for it?

Comment: as for me , i will ask both

Answer (score 4, accepted):

EDIT: As to what an extrema is:  Extrema are maximums and minimums--over its whole "lifetime" how high and how low does a function go?

Original post:

Many, many processes in "real life" can be represented by functions.  These applications can range in topic from physics (for example, the velocity of an object), to financial (cost to produce a certain quantity of goods), to the mundane (how much water you use per day, on an average basis).

Finding the extreme values of the functions is done whenever knowing the max or min is necessary.  For example--how high will my model rocket go?  That's a calculus problem.

Another example would be to find the maximal profit you can earn with a certain production method.  Or, what is the maximal volume of a box that uses a fixed amount of material (or even a minimal amount of material)?  What is the minimum amount of fencing to be used for your cattle herd?

These are just some simple examples--there are thousands of applications out there, it is just a matter of finding a process and needing to maximize or minimize its output.

Comment: "Another example would be to find the maximal profit you can earn with a certain production method. Or, what is the maximal volume of a box that uses a fixed amount of material (or even a minimal amount of material)? What is the minimum amount of fencing to be used for your cattle herd?"-------here u gave some real life example , i appreciate for that .But i got another question  .
"for finding these maximum or minimum of  these problems do we use the common calculus procedure  ?  like cut and make sum  " ?

Comment: @tun "what is the maximal volume of a box that uses a fixed amount of material". This belongs to the [calculus of variations](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Calculus_of_variations).

Answer (score 0):

In analysis of differentiable real-valued functions of a single argument, an extremum is usually defined to be a place where the derivative is zero.

$$ x_0 \text{ is an extremum of } f(x) \text{ iff } f'(x_0) = 0 $$

To identify an extremum as a local maximum, minimum or an inflection point, you look at the second derivative:

$$ x_0 \text{ is a local maximum of } f(x) \text{ iff } f'(x_0)=0\text{ and } f''(x_0)<0  $$
$$ x_0 \text{ is a local minimum of } f(x) \text{ iff } f'(x_0)=0\text{ and } f''(x_0)>0  $$
$$ x_0 \text{ is an inflection point of } f(x) \text{ iff } f'(x_0)= f''(x_0) = 0  $$

Comment: First, if $f'(x_0)=f''(x_0)=0$ and $f^{(3)}(x_0)\not=0$ do you consider that $f$ has an extremum at $x_0$. Second, we say f has an extremum at $x_0$ and not "$x_0$ is an extremum of $f$". Third, your definitions imply that if $f'(x_0)=f''(x_0)=f^{(3)}(x_0)=0\not=f^{(4)}(x_0)$ then $x_0$ is a turning point of $f$.

Comment: @metacompactness 1) Yes. 2) English is my second language, I was taught all this in Danish and that is a technicality of language, I can write all this in formula. 3) I am not sure in my definitions on what that would imply for these definitions, this is an edge case.

Comment: Well, english is my 2nd language too. Anw, does $f(x)=x^3$ have an extremum at $x_0=0$?

Comment: @metacompactness, in this case we say that zero is an inflection point.

Comment: @Sigur Of course it is an inflection point but not an extremum. But according to the 1st definition of karl it is an extremum.

Comment: @Sigur inflection point is exactly the term I was missing. Edited.

Answer (score 0):

An extremum (plural: extrema) is a maximum (plural: maxima) or a minimum.

Let $f$ be a function on $I\subset\mathbb{R}$ and let $x_0\in\ I$. We say that $f$ have a local maximum (resp. local minimum) at $x_0$ if $f(x)<f(x_0)$ (resp. $f(x)>f(x_0)$) in the strict neighborhood of $x_0$ (i.e. $|x-x_0|<\epsilon$ for some $\epsilon>0$ and $x\not=x_0$).

$f$ have a global maximum (resp. global minimum) at $x_0$ if $f(x)<f(x_0)$ (resp. $f(x)>f(x_0)$) for all $x\in I$.

The definitions are clear but the problem of finding $x_0$ directly from the definition is often very difficult so we usually use the techniques of calculus (the use of derivatives).

**Note:** if $I$ is compact then $f$ has a global maximum and a global minimum.